# Who can see Force Ghosts?

Tags: star-wars, force-ghost

In Star Wars, the only person who meets a ghost of a Jedi is Luke Skywalker, who is a Force sensitive (and a Jedi).

But can ordinary people (who aren't force-sensitive) see a Jedi ghost ?

In this scene (Star Wars VI), Luke is looking at Obi-Wan, Yoda, and Anakin Skywalker, who are ghosts.

[image]

Is he the only one who can see them ?

Comment: Timothy Zahn's Thrawn trilogy of novels states that Artoo could never see who Luke was talking to on Dagobah. I'm not sure if it explicitly states who might have been able to see him - it might be that only biologicals (as opposed to droids) might have been able to see them).

Comment: @Darren - Obligatory mention of [Skippy the Jedi Droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid) :-)